# According to Eclipse, why is the standard jar file extension ".jar;*.zip"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, file-extension

I tried to export a runnable Jar, and Eclipse said:

> You have used the extension ".jar" at the end of the name. The standard extension is ".jar;*.zip".
>
> You can choose to use the standard extension instead.
>
> [Use .jar;*.zip]                     [Cancel]        [Use .jar]

(See screenshot below.)

Is there some sort of massive misunderstanding on my part here? Because ".jar;*.zip" really does not sound like a file extension to me. Why would it (Eclipse Luna 4.4.0) not want me to save it (a standard Java program) as a .jar? Just to be clear, it lets me and everything works, but why the warning?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's a bug. You should file a bug report.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in Eclipse.

Comment: @dimo414 Sorry; I didn't know that when I posted the question -- for all I knew, maybe that was the standard extension. What should I do now, delete the question?

Comment: I'd leave for other people searching for an answer.   You might beef it up with an exact sequence of actions that get you to this point...

Comment: @raxod502 not a criticism, simply housekeeping.  If you don't think this will be helpful for future visitors (as would be the case if this is just a bug in Eclipse that gets fixed) you can delete it.  If, as rcook suggests, it could be helpful in the future, there's no need.

Comment: @dimo414 That's not off-topic. Questions about tools used primarily for programming are [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Software issues involving IDEs, in particular, are considered on-topic at SO.

Comment: @AdiInbar True, but it's not an ongoing question, it's a bug that (presumably) will be filed and resolved.  It's absolutely a valid issue to raise, but I'm unsure SO is the proper venue.  As mentioned, if there's Q&A value to this post, I've no objection to it staying open.

Comment: @dimo414 Do you or someone else want to add one of these comments as an answer, or should I?

Comment: You can feel free to; include a link to the bug you filed, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441436).